# Adjust paginated api call to enable refresh in PowerBI Service (M)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm reworking a dashboard that is fine on PBI desktop but can't refresh on PBi service because it includes dynamic data sources (meta api). I'm trying to adjust the original code following [Chris Webb's blog](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/08/16/using-the-relativepath-and-query-options-with-web-contents-in-power-query-and-power-bi-m-code/) explanation to 'un-dynamise" the query (use of Query and RelativePath in Web.Contents).
However, with my adjusted code, I'm only able to retrieve 60 days of data, whereas it was supposed to pull 12 months worth of data. I don't understand where the breaks happen.

**Original Code:**

```
let
initUntil = Number.ToText(todayInSeconds),
initSince = Number.ToText(@get30DaysBefore(todayInSeconds)),
baseUri = "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/ "&facebookPageID&"/insights?metric=metrics&period=day&since="&initSince&"&until="&initUntil&"&access_token="&metaPageToken,
initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseUri)),
initData = initReq[data],

gather = (data as list, uri as text , i as number) =>
let
newUri = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri))[paging][previous],
newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri)),
newData = newReq[data],
data = List.Combine({data, newData}),

check = if Table.Contains(Record.ToTable(newReq[paging]), [Name = "previous"]) = false then data else if i > 20 then data else @gather(data, newUri, i+1)
in
check,

outputList = if Table.Contains(Record.ToTable(initReq[paging]), [Name = "previous"]) = true then @gather(initData, baseUri, 1) else initData,
//End of relevant code
```

**Adjusted Code (works partially)**

```
let

initUntil = Number.ToText(todayInSeconds),
initSince = Number.ToText(@get30DaysBefore(todayInSeconds)),

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/XXXXXXXXX/ ",
options = [RelativePath = "insights?",Query = [metric = metrics,period="day",since=initSince,until=initUntil,access_token=metaPageToken]],
initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, options)),

initData = initReq[data],

gather = (data as list, url, options , i as number) =>
let
newUri = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, options))[paging][previous],
newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri)),
newData = newReq[data],
data = List.Combine({data, newData}),

check = if Table.Contains(Record.ToTable(newReq[paging]), [Name = "previous"]) = false then data else if i > 20 then data else @gather(data, url, options, i+1)
in
check,

outputList = if Table.Contains(Record.ToTable(initReq[paging]), [Name = "previous"]) = true then @gather(initData, url, options, 1) else initData,
// End of code
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I dont understand how this should work.  @gather(data, url, options, i+1) calls the function recursively but the i is never used in the Web.Contents and wont impact anything, and the values for url and options never change either, so you are effectively calling the same Web.Contents command over and over.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, that is what I don't get from the original code. I believe i is just to index the # of recursion and that the uri gets updated by calling [previous] paging in newUri.

Comment: The code seems to be calling the same thing over and over. There needs to be some part where it changes the contents of options being fed to the function.  I obviously can't try the code, so am not sure how to additionally help

Answer (score 0):

For documentation purposes, here is the solution I found to my issue (and it fully works) =>

```
let

initUntil = Number.ToText(todayInSeconds),
initSince = Number.ToText(@get30DaysBefore(todayInSeconds)),

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/",
StartingOptions = [RelativePath = "v15.0/xxxxxxxx/insights?metric=page_views_total,page_post_engagements,page_consumptions,page_consumptions_unique,page_impressions,page_impressions_unique,page_posts_impressions,page_posts_impressions_unique,page_fans,page_fan_adds&period=day",
Query = [since=initSince,until=initUntil,access_token=metaPageToken]],

initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://graph.facebook.com/", StartingOptions)),

initData = initReq[data],


gather = (data as list, QparmSince, QparmUntil, i as number) =>
   let     
       baseurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/",
       token = metaPageToken,
       StartingOptions =[RelativePath = "v15.0/xxxxxxxx/insights?metric=page_views_total,page_post_engagements,page_consumptions,page_consumptions_unique,page_impressions,page_impressions_unique,page_posts_impressions,page_posts_impressions_unique,page_fans,page_fan_adds&period=day",
Query = [since=QparmSince,until=QparmUntil,access_token=token]],
       newSince = Text.BetweenDelimiters(Text.From(Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseurl, StartingOptions))[paging][previous]), "&since=", "&"),
       newUntil = Text.BetweenDelimiters(Text.From(Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseurl, StartingOptions))[paging][previous]), "&until=", "&"),
       newOptions = [RelativePath = "v15.0/xxxxxxx/insights?metric=page_views_total,page_post_engagements,page_consumptions,page_consumptions_unique,page_impressions,page_impressions_unique,page_posts_impressions,page_posts_impressions_unique,page_fans,page_fan_adds&period=day",
Query = [since=newSince,until=newUntil,access_token=token]],
       newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseurl, newOptions)),
       newData = newReq[data],

       data = List.Combine({data, newData}),
    
       check = if Table.Contains(Record.ToTable(newReq[paging]), [Name = "previous"]) = false then data else if i > 20 then data else @gather(data, newSince, newUntil, i+1)
   in 
       check,

outputList = if Table.Contains(Record.ToTable(initReq[paging]), [Name = "previous"]) = true then @gather(initData, initSince, initUntil, 1) else initData,
```

The trick was to update within the @gather function the Since and Until query parameters by extracting them from the "Previous" paging of the Meta Api.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).